# Hagamos [aws] sinónimo de [amazon-web-services]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Actualmente tenemos

- [aws](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws) con 62 preguntas al momento de escribir la pregunta.
- [amazon-web-services](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) con 5 preguntas al momento de escribir la pregunta.

ambas tratan de exactamente lo mismo.

Podría debatirse el hecho de hacer sinónimo

- [aws](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws) ← [amazon-web-services](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services)
- o, [amazon-web-services](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) ← [aws](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws)

[aws](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws) tiene más preguntas que [amazon-web-services](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services), pero hacerlo así podría ser problemático ya que no todos saben que las siglas de Amazon Web Services son AWS, fuera de eso ambas deberían ser sinónimos.

Un detalle a tomar en cuenta es que en [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [la etiqueta [aws] es sinónimo de [amazon-web-services]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-web-services/synonyms).

Comment: Si se hacen sinónimos, cuando alguien empiece escribir `amazon...` le sugerirá la etiqueta [tag:aws] diciendo "además: [tag:amazon-web-services]". Veamos un ejemplo con esta misma pregunta, si uno se pone a añadir la etiqueta `status-com...`--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fweg.png. Por tanto, nada se perderá si se marca [tag:aws] como principal, la gente la "encontrará" sin problema.

Comment: Cambio hecho. AWS como la principal dado que fue la más usada y conocida. un saludo